# Seeking equivalent to QGIS Mask plugin to use in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, qgis-plugins, arcgis-pro

Is there any (easy) solution to replace my use of Mask plugin for QGIS in ArcGIS Pro?

The mask plugin for QGIS let you create in one click a new mask layer with visibility option for labels.

> This plugin allows user to quickly transform a polygon selection into
> a map masking layer or a region of interest, following symbology
> choice. The plugin allows also to spatially filter labeling of other
> layer, so that labels will only appear in the Region of Interest.

Mask plugin for QGIS repo: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mask/

I'am looking for the same function within ArcGis Pro.

Comment: Please [edit] the Question to describe the desired functionality, instead of relying on folks to follow a link.

Comment: Don't know if this has been included in ArcGIS PRO but in ArcMap the data frame properties has an option to "cut" according to different thing and to exclude layer from being cut (this https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/clipping-the-data-frame.htm)

Comment: [Clip layers](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/help/mapping/properties/clip-layers-in-a-map.htm)?

Comment: Clip layers is a good answer. As of today I didn't found a solution to apply a transparency clipping option.